# L5 Pagination keeping current url variables when changing pages

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

So I am trying to paginate a set of results in Laravel 5.

```
$listings = $query->paginate(16);
```

Then on my view I'm using this to display the pagination links.

```
{!! $listings>appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

I want to retain all the GET variables in the URL when changing pages.

When I try to load a page I get this error:

> Call to undefined function appends()

I know pagination has been modified in L5 but can't seem to find out how to get it to work.

I don't see the logic for changing pagination from how it was in L4 but that's another story.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: In case you know what would possibly be those GET parameters you can append them: `$listings->appends(array('color' => 'red'))->links();` ?

Comment: I know the names of the parameters but not their contents. There's a list of parameters that might be in the URL or may not, and theyre values are variable also.

Comment: So maybe, prior to the `appends` function you can create an array with all the parameters as keys, and the values would be the $_GET values in case they set or an empty string/int in case they aren't. For instance: `$params = array('color' => (isset($_GET['color']) ? $_GET['color'] : '' );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the "-" in your method call $listings`-`>appends

Comment: You sir are a genius! ;) Working!